# Showing toast before an intesive work of processor

Tags: java, android

I need to show a Toast message before a method using an intense processor work. The problem is that the Toast only shows after this method, even calling this method in another Thread.

How can i show the Toast before ?

EDIT: The code is too long for showing here ... but i will resume it ...

...

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
proccess.setRun();
```

//In the Proccess class that implements Runnable ...

```
public void setRun(){
    thread= new Thread(this);
    thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    thread.start();
    running=true;
}
public void run() {
        bytes=byteGrooveMaker();
        prepare(grBytes);
}
```

//byteGrooveMaker() is a method in Proccess class that requires lot of processor work.

Comment: Can you share the code for the section you are referring to?

Comment: You should show the Toast on the UI thread, and then start your background thread to do the intensive work. Please post the relevant code so we can understand better what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an async task. On the onpreexecute you show your toast, and in the doinbackground method you execute your heavy process :)

Comment: There are literally dozens of examples on SO of how to implement an async task. Just do a quick google search

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do "intensive" processing in Android is to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

There is (almost always) some example code in the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Call me old fashioned for recommending a book, but O'Reilly has an excellent book "[Learning Android](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010883.do)" which walks the reader through building a complete application.  Also, as a side benefit, the sample code can be downloaded (Look for the `StatusActivity` in the "Yamba" application for an example of `AsyncTask`.

Sample code can be downloaded here: http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920010883/

Answer (score 0):

Try to include a little delay in the intense process thread so the Toast is shown before de process begins.